# What is the correct syntax for a Redis JSON SET call with the NX flag in a Node.js app?

Tags: json, npm, redis

I have a Node.js app that uses the Redis NPM module.  I am trying to set a JSON key to a specific value but only if it does not exist.  The Redis JSON [docs](https://redis.io/commands/json.set/) for the non-JSON `SET` call say:

> The optional subcommands modify this behavior for both new RedisJSON
> data type keys as well as the JSON Object keys in them:
>
> - `NX` - only set the key if it does not already exist
> - `XX` - only set the key if it already exists

So I tried the following syntax in my Redis JSON SET call:

```js
const successFailCode = await (self.redisClient.json.set(redisKey, '$', worldConferenceInitializationCountObj,  'nx'))
```

But that does not work.  Every time I make that call it *always* sets the object instead of only executing the `SET` operation if the key does not already exist.

I tried inspecting the NPM `redis` code, but it is highly abstracted TypeScript code that is hard for me to follow so I can't determine the proper way, if it is at all possible, to pass the `NX` flag to the Redis JSON `SET` call.

**NOTE**: I know I can first make a `get` call to see if the key exists, and *then* do the `set` call, but that opens up my app to a potential race condition where one client checks to see if the key exists, finds out it does not, and then before it executes the `SET` operation another client executes its `SET` operation first.  So when the first client executes (erroneously) its `SET` call it overwrites the `SET` operation of the second client.

Can anyone give me the correct syntax for making the Redis JSON `SET` call using the `NX` flag?

Comment: `{ NX: true }`, per https://github.com/redis/node-redis#redis-commands? You can see `'nx'` isn't a valid options argument in https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/2a8e11a51d4f965b2d902bd8e6b041f04d984182/packages/json/lib/commands/SET.ts#L5-L13.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks.  I take it you are skilled in TypeScript?  How did you know how to get to that TransformArguments() code from the NPM module index file, if you don't mind me asking?  Thanks for the edit too.

Comment: I use TS regularly but not _particularly_ skilled, I'm no [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz). I just went to the GitHub repo and drilled through what seemed like the obvious folders: packages, json, lib, commands, SET.